# Can one Java Application monitor another Java Application on the same Linux machine?

Tags: java, linux, monitor

On a Linux machine, I have an existing 3rd party Java Application running.
I can know the application real time status by going to the /proc/PID/ directory (Memory, thread, etc).
However, I want to run a separated Java program on the same machine to do that without using JConsole or VisualVM(like production environment).
I searched topic for JMX. However, it only returns info about its own program, not the 3rd party application I am trying to monitoring. Am I right?
Is there a way to do that(other than parsing the /proc/PID/ result)?
Thanks!

Follow the suggestion, I wrote a simple program to do local monitor. However, I got the following error. Any idea?

```
    String hostName = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
    int portNum = xxxx;
    try {
        JMXServiceURL u = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + hostName + ":" + portNum +  "/jmxrmi");
        JMXConnector c = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(u);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

------Output------
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338)
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:207)
at test.main(test.java:57)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:99)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:185)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1886)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1856)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:255)
... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you modify the program to be monitored? It's relatively simple to make it transmit statistics over the network(loopback) for instance.

Comment: Do want to know if the java process is running? or more specific things.

Comment: I can't modify the existing Java application since it is a 3rd party product. I want to monitor its memory usage, thread counter, etc and generate an alarm if the percentage exceeds some threshold.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what JMX is for. Every java application is automatically exposed for monitoring and management by JMX agents if you're running java 6 or later -- if you're on an earlier version you need to set a system property when you start the app.

You may even monitor it from a different computer, using JXM remote, which uses RMI under the hood.

Some resources:

- [Oracle monitoring and management guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/toc.html)
- [Visual VM article](https://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html)

Comment: Enabling the Out-of-the-Box Management
To monitor a Java platform using the JMX API, you must do the following.

Enable the JMX agent (another name for the platform MBean server) when you start the Java VM. You can enable the JMX agent for:

Local monitoring, for a client management application running on the local system.

Remote monitoring, for a client management application running on a remote system.

Monitor the Java VM with a tool that complies to the JMX specification, such as JConsole. See Chapter 3, Using JConsole for more information about Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Linux and only need CPU, Memory and Threads you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` passing as parameter the linux the command  `ps -p <pid> -o pid,nlwp,pcpu,pmem --sort pcpu`. Of course you still need to parse the output. It's something like this:

```
PID   NLWP  %CPU  %MEM
1765   52    4.6  11.3
```

Where `NLWP` is the number of threads in the process.

Answer (score 0):

For local monitoring for my 3rd party application, replacing
JMXServiceURL u = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + hostName + ":" + portNum +  "/jmxrmi");
by
JMXServiceURL u = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + hostName + ":" + portNum +  "/server");
resolved the issue for javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi.
Memory and thread monitoring work fine now.
Thanks for all the inputs!